# Why is $(A\times B)/(I\times J)=A/I\times B/J$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Why is it true that $(A\times B)/(I\times J)=A/I\times B/I$? Here, $A$ and $B$ are (commutative) rings (with $1$), and $I$ and $J$ are respective ideals.

This looks similar to the chinese remainder theorem, but I'm not sure how this is (if it is at all) an application of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the map
$$
f\colon A\times B\to (A/I)\times(B/J),\qquad f(a,b)=(a+I,b+J)
$$
and

1. prove $f$ is a ring homomorphism;
2. find its kernel;
3. apply the homomorphism theorem.